# Unable to fetch selected options from multi-select dropdown list inside post. node.js

Tags: node.js, post, ejs, multi-select

I have a multi-select dropdown whose selected option values I am accessing in the post request at server-side. the below method has worked for me before. But it isn't working now and returns only the last selected option value. I have researched but most of the methods answered only how it works in PHP etc...

The form

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Tags*: (Please Choose Min 5 Tags)</label>
      <select name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control" multiple> 
          <% if(tagList == null || tagList == undefined){%>
              <option value="">No tags to show</option>
          <%}else{%>
              <% for(var tag of tagList){%>
                  <option value="<%=tag._id%>"><%=tag.tagName%></option>
              <%}%>
          <%}%>
       </select>
     </div>  
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Create">
         <button type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Inside post request

```
.post((req, res, next) => { 
   let tags = req.body.tags;
   console.log(tags); //returns only the last selected option value
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your code is ok. Did you change something?

Comment: @dimitristseggenes no I haven't changed anything.

Comment: try to hardcode option values and check if it works

Comment: I did, but it still gives me only the last selected option value.